# Groovy SOAPUI - ssh(port 22) then port forward 3306 to access the database

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am looking to tunnel via ssh(port 22) then port forward 3306 to access the database - SOAP UI groovy. This is what I have so far I am not able to run this code successfully.

```
package mypackage
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.*
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session


// ssh login
def sshHost = 'test'
def sshUser = 'test'
def sshPass = 'test'
def sshPort = 22

// database login
def targetHost = '127.0.0.1'
def targetUser = 'test'
def targetPass = 'test'
def targetPort = '3306'

JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, sshPort);
session.setPassword(sshPass);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
session.connect();
int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(0, targetHost, targetPort);

Connection con = null;
def driver = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
def connectionString = 'jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db'
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, targetUser, targetPass);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = "select * company "
st.execute(sql);
```

Here is the error i get:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script23.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.jcraft.jsch.JSch @ line 4, column 1. import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class com.jcraft.jsch.JSch @ line 4, column 1. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1145) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:138) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Script23.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class com.jcraft.jsch.Session @ line 5, column 1. import com.jcraft.jsch.Session ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class com.jcraft.jsch.Session @ line 5, column 1. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1145) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:138) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2 errors

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial error.

> unexpected token: package @ line 2, column 1. package mypackage ^

Move the statement `package mypackage` from 2nd line to 1st line.

**UPDATE1:** after fixing the above suggested change, OP updated the question with different error. So adding the additional information.

`jsh` and its dependency libraries needs to be copied under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory and restart soapui tool.

Comment: The earlier error is gone. But you updated with different error which should be different one to deal with.

Comment: I will try to fix that. However, do you think the code looks good? am I missing anything?

Comment: I meant to say the overall approach?

Comment: I have already provided you the link with complete solution. So, it should be ok as long as you just follow that link. And see the updated answer based upon the new error.